# php script not entering into the database

Tags: php

I have been following the tutorials on youtube by mmtuts and got to the section, how to insert database from mysqli. It was working well for a while and I managed to insert information into the database but suddenly, it fails to insert into the database. It just seems that it is not connecting to my database but I can insert it manually.... Here are my codes.. I have the main database file in my includes folder...

```
 <?php

          $dbServername = "localhost";
          $dbUsername = "root";
          $dbPassword = "";
          $dbName = "loginsystem";

          $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

          ?>
```

This is my main registration page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form action="includes/signup.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first_name">
      <br></br>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="last_name">
      <br></br>
     <input type="text" name="email_address" placeholder="email_address">
     <br></br>
     <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password">
     <br></br>
     <input type="text" name="confirm_password" 
     placeholder="confirm_password">
     <br></br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
   </form>


 </body>
  </html>
```

This is the page where it processed the information to be inserted into the database..

```
<?php


  include_once 'dbh.php';

   $token1 = 'sfdsfdsfsfsdferewgagQWEDFGRTRTRGFGDFG123245345433!~';
   $token1 = str_shuffle($token1);
   $token1 = substr($token1, 0, 10);




 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, 
  user_pwd, token) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address', 
  '$password','$confirm_password', '$token1');";  // needs duoble quote

  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header('Location:../includes/activateaccount.php?signup=success');

  ?>
```

This is my activateaccount.php page:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.php';


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> Please enter the following information to activate your account</p>
    <form action='activate.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='email_address' placeholder='email_address'>
        <input type='text' name='confirm_email' placeholder='confirm_email'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' values='activate account'>
    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, there are no errors displayed but it just doesn't add into the database....

Comment: Im confused, is the problem in `includes/signup.php` or `activate.php`? Also your query is vulnerable to SQL injection so if you're inputting a character such as `'` your code will break

Comment: Get [MySQLi errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to display aswell.

Comment: __NEVER__ _ever_ store plain passwords in your database. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: I have checked your code, there is no error in your code, it should work.

Comment: Thanks guys but for some reason... my other database is working but not this one and i will be doing a password hash eventually.....it saya returning zero results.. i think the problem is in sign up but i have the dbh file saved in the includes folder

Comment: Hello.... I think I can't post anymore replies

Comment: that is weird... I thought I was banned from this site because of the down votes

Comment: it says that I can't ask anymore questions from this account, why?